# Вывод даты в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть плагин, который выводит дату для событий, нужно как-то поменять окончания месяцев, которые он выводит **(не "14 февраль", а "14 февраля")**.

Где это примерно можно посмотреть?

Плагин **"Events Schedule WP Plugin"**, скриншот прилагаю.

В файле **.pot** языка плагина нет ничего связанного с месяцами, откуда он берет наименования?

P.S. Пробовал перевести основной файл **.po** вордпресса, тоже не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я помню в ВП давно исправлен этот косяк. Судя по всему плагин из эпохи доисторического материализма. А репо такого нет. Как он что выводит - вопрос. Почему не воспользоваться нормальными плагами, из оф репо?

Comment: Да он не старый вроде как, пользовался потому что мне нужно было вот такой короткий calendar list выводить и дополнять удобно. https://codecanyon.net/item/events-schedule-wordpress-plugin/14907462

Comment: Скачай сайт полностью себе на комп. Открой любой IDE (PhpStorm, Notepad++, SublimeText3), выдели все файлы и папки сайта через шифт, нажми "Поиск в файлах" или что-то похожее по смыслу и введи "Февраль". Тебе откроется языковой файл. Вобще, возможно теоритически, плагин берет названия откуда-то из языковых файлов вордпресса, так что повнимательнее

Comment: Ничего вы не найдете. Вывод, скорее всего, идет из функций php. Что-то вроде `echo date_i18n('d F');` Там жестко прописано - `Январь, Февраль` и т.д. Чтобы что-то поменять, надо править код плагина. Получать номер месяца и по нему выводить название на русском в нужном падеже.

Comment: Я тоже не могу найти ваш плагин. Дайте ссылку на него.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GoUBdD3BPk1hBZGCr3E4QiclBShe1BMr - вот, с хостинга скачал.

Comment: Действительно, ничего не нашел и понять не могу, к чему обращаются классы плагина.

Comment: Пробовал в functions.php вставить код отсюда, тоже не помогает. http://n-wp.ru/24135

Comment: Вы когда кому-то конкретно пишете, используйте @AliceKhip Я случайно увидел ваше новое сообщение

Comment: Ну и что я говорил? В плагине все даты выводятся через `date_i18n`

Comment: @AliceKhip покажите html в dev tools, чтобы понять, откуда идет вывод вашего проблемного фрагмента

Comment: @KAGGDesign Вот, http://screenshot.ru/upload/images/2018/01/08/Untitled-18e75f.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Веселый вам плагин достался. Можно пропустить весь детектив и сразу читать секцию **TL;DR**. А можно и полюбопытствовать.

Из вашего скриншота в последнем комментарии к вопросу видно, что результирующий html такой:

```
<time datetime="....." class="wcs-class__time">
```

Такого кода в плагине нет, зато есть

```
<time :datetime="event.start" class="wcs-class__time">
```

в файле `wp-content/plugins/weekly-class/templates/display/list-plain.php`

Файл этот по виду и содержанию - шаблон для вывода событий. Покопавшись в коде плагина, удалось выяснить что он вызывается вот такой конструкцией:

```
$template = locate_template( array( "{$slug}-{$name}.php", apply_filters( 'wcs_template_path', 'wcs_templates/' ) . "{$slug}-{$name}.php" ) );
```

из которой понятно, что шаблоны можно перенести в папку текущей темы, в подпапку wcs_templates. Я скопировал содержимое list-plain.php в `wp-content/themes/test/wcs_templates/display/list-plain.php`, сделал косметические изменения и убедился, что шаблон вызывается из моей темы test.

Казалось бы - правим шаблон list-plain.php и задача решена. Не тут-то было. Что за event.start внутри? И что за двоеточие?

```
<time :datetime="event.start" class="wcs-class__time">
```

Оказывается, это только полуфабрикат конечного кода html, окончательный html создается с помощью javascript. При этом информация о выводимых событиях запрашивается через ajax, примерно так:

```
this.$http.get( ajaxurl, { params: { action: 'wcs_get_events_json', content: typeof this.options.content !== 'undefined' ? this.options.content : [], start: this.start, end: this.stop, limit: this.getLimit } } ).then( this.responseSuccess, this.responseError );
```

Этот запрос отрабатывается в php, в функции `get_events_json`, но самое интересное, что время и дата возвращаются во внутреннем формате, без форматирования.

Оказывается, вывод даты форматирует js, с использованием библиотеки `moment.js`, примерно так:

```
start: typeof $default_options.ts_start !== 'undefined' ? $default_options.ts_start : moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
```

Что делать? Я попробовал подменить `moment.js` его международной версией `moment-with-locales.js`, скачанной с сайта https://momentjs.com. Понятно, не редактированием самого плагина (иначе все слетит при обновлении), а с помощью `wp_deregister_script( 'wcs-moment' );` и регистрации `moment-with-locales.js`. Работает, но надо еще как-то сделать вызов

```
moment.locale('ru');
```

С этим возникли проблемы. Похоже, при активации скрипта - слишком рано, по jQuery.ready - поздно. Пришлось сделать чуть более коряво, но зато этот способ работает.

Плагин добавляет локализацию `wcs_moment_locale` в свой скрипт `wcs-main`. Именно благодаря этой локализации мы видим русские названия месяцев при выводе. Я запустил еще одну локализацию, позже, с приоритетом 20 события `wp_enqueue_scripts`. И это работает. Вот как выглядит результирующий код.

**TL;DR**

Добавьте в `functions.php` вашей темы:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_767963_localize_scripts', 20 );
function so_767963_localize_scripts() {
    global $wp_locale;

    $month = array(
        'Января',
        'Февраля',
        'Марта',
        'Апреля',
        'Мая',
        'Июня',
        'Июля',
        'Августа',
        'Сентября',
        'Октября',
        'Ноября',
        'Декабря',
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'wcs-main', 'wcs_moment_locale', array(
        'firstDay'      => intval( get_option( 'start_of_week' ) ),
        'months'        => array_values( $month ),
        'monthsShort'   => array_values( $wp_locale->month_abbrev ),
        'weekdays'      => array_values( $wp_locale->weekday ),
        'weekdaysShort' => array_values( $wp_locale->weekday_abbrev ),
        'weekdaysMin'   => array_values( $wp_locale->weekday_initial ),
    ) );
}
```

**That's all, folks :)**

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Не думал, что кто-то будет всерьез копаться и разбираться в особенностях работы этого плагина. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Конечно, полезен. Сделано!